# What is an interaction?

Tags: metaphysics

I am currently researching about process metaphysics where the world around us is understood as a population of processes: every existent as a process and as part of larger process(es). Have referred to Johanna Seibt, Nicholas Rescher to define process, however, it is something I am still thinking about. 
What is a process? What is an interaction? How does an interaction relate to a process?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to philosophy.SE! I've edited your question so it doesn't ask for our thoughts or discussion. Subjective questions are not necessarily verboten but [we do favor objective questions here.](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: I am not familiar with the authors you mention. At least at one time there was a website for process philosophy, it might still be in existence. I associate Whitehead (I'm sure there are others too) with such thinking, but it's been a long time since I looked into it. There may be different approaches to this idea that I am not aware of.

Comment: Also, if applicable, and if we have a tag, you might want to add one on "process philosophy".

Comment: You can read my "theory of Interaction" proposal, check the links on my profile. Sorry for the publicity, but I find amazing that we have many static descriptions of systems (systems theory), but nobody seems to pay attention to the systems dynamics (no generic interactions theories were ever proposed! All interactional assessments refer only to a specific entities, none to generic systems). I'm sure this will grow with time.

Comment: "We don't understand the world as made by stones — by things. We understand the world made by kisses, or things like kisses: happenings.” -  Carlo Rovelli

Answer (score 1):

An interaction is when 2 or more systems influence each other.

To relate that to processes it's sufficient to say that a process needs interactions to exists, otherwise it would not happen.

As an example, let's have some piece of metal be chemically treated to remove undesired elements. The chemicals involved interact with each other and with the undesired materials/chemicals that make that piece of metal less pure. The process of purifying the metal happens.

There is no reason not to apply this same logic from a metaphysical perspective.